# Disable Submit Button error in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have created a contact form that has a disabled submit button until all fields have been filled out and vallidated.

The issue I am having is that the Submit stays disabled on IE, even when all fields are validated, so the user is unable to send the form.

I've tried a number of ways to add different code for the submit button but with no success.

My code is as follows:

JQuery

```
$(function() {
$(":text").keypress(check_submit).each(function() {
check_submit();
   });
});

function check_submit() {
if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
$(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
} else {
$(":submit").attr("disabled", false);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php" id="commentForm">
      <label for="Name" id="Name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" class="required"/><br  /><br />



        <label for="Email" id="Email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Email" class="required"/><br  /><br />
        <label for="Location" id="Location">Location:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Location" class="required"/><br  /><br />


        <label for="Phone" id="Phone">Tel No:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Phone" class="required"/><br  /><br />

        <label for="Message" id="Message">Message:</label><br />
        <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="40" class="required"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_btn" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` isn't referring to what you want when you call the function that way, instead it should be:

```
$(function() {
  $(":text").keypress(check_submit).each(check_submit);
});

function check_submit() {
  $(":submit").attr("disabled", $(this).val().length == 0);
}
```

...but this whole approach is flawed, since validating on any filled in field would enable the submit, instead you need to loop through and see if *any* are empty, not just the last one with a keypress, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(":text").bind("keyup change", check_submit).change();
});

function check_submit() {
  var anyEmpty = false;
  $(":text").each(function() { 
    if($(this).val().length==0) { anyEmpty = true; return false; }
  });
  $(":submit").attr("disabled", anyEmpty);
}
```

Comment: The submit button is still disabled until I refresh the page and then it works fine. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Yes - the error I'm getting is: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: @Micanio -ah, see *that's* the issue, what's it happening on?

Comment: Line 40, char 3 which is this line: $(":text").each(function()

Comment: @Micanio - you sure your `<script>` tags for including jQuery are correct?

Comment: Script tags are fine - I'm also using JQuery Validation and Cufon as well, if thats any help...

Comment: and what happens if you change $(":text") --> to: $('input[type=text]')?
As far as I know, it's equivalent to $('input:text'), but maybe IE does have some problems with the previous.

Comment: @Micanio - do you have a link to the page?  Something's happening to cause your error, would be easiest if I could see the page in question.

Comment: @Micanio - it's blowing up on the `:text` selector, something about the cufron I believe, try putting `$("input:text, textarea")` instead of `$(":text")` and `$("input:submit")` instead of just `$(":submit")`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function check_submit() {
if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
$(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
} else {
$(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think 
$(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled"); is more correct because of the XHTML syntax.
Besides, you have this row in your function: "if ($(this).val().length == 0)", but $(this) may not be used correctly, so the element id or something similar could be passed to the function.

Comment: Nick spotted that the event hookup isn't working as expected.  I didn't.  :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter -it's not more correct, you're thinking **attributes**, not **DOM properties**, this is a boolean.

Comment: @Nick Craver: OK, thanks, this means $(":submit").attr("disabled", true); is correct, but $(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled"); does work correctly too (at least it does work for me - I don't know if it does matter that I use the XHTML Strict syntax in other parts of my code).
Or if my solution doesn't work in all browsers, than maybe I didn't try enough. Do you know about any known problems about that?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - it's not that it doesn't work...it's just not doing what you think, any non-empty string is truey, you could put `$(":submit").attr("disabled", "wombats");` and it would have the same effect ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver: wow, I understand, thanks, I've learnt something new today. :)